# Show that the matrix equality

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be $n\times n$ matrices  and let $b_1$ and $b_2$ be $n\times 1$ vectors.

Comment: No, the equality is true even for nonsingular $A_1$ and $A_2$

Comment: This is impossible unless there are further properties. If $b_1$ is an $A_1$ eigenvector for example, $S$ will not be well defined, because the matrix on the right will not be invertible.

Comment: Perhaps this is true if we add the requirement that $b_i$ be cyclic for $A_i$, that is that $k[A_1]b_1=V=k[A_2]b_2$. That seems reasonable.

Comment: Please see my edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K$ be the base field.

With your edits, consider $SA_1S^{-1}A_2^kb_2$ for each $0\le k\le n-1$.
When $k < n-1$, we have 
$$SA_1S^{-1}A_2^kb_2 = SA_1A_1^kb_1 = SA_1^{k+1}b_1 = A_2^{k+1}b_2 = A_2 (A_2^kb_2).$$

Now let $p(t)= \chi_{A_1}(t)=\chi_{A_2}(t)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A_1$, which is the same as the characteristic polynomial of $A_2$, since they are similar. 
$$p(t) = t^n + a_{n-1}t^{n-1}+\cdots + a_0,$$
for some constants $a_i\in K$. By Cayley-Hamilton, $p(A_1)=p(A_2)=0$, so 
$$A_1^n = -\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_iA_1^i,\text{ and }
A_2^n = -\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_iA_2^i.
$$

Now for $k=n-1$, we have
$$SA_1S^{-1}A_2^kb_2 = SA_1A_1^{n-1}b_1 = SA_1^nb_1
$$
$$ = -S\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_iA_1^ib_1
$$
$$= -\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_iA_2^i b_2
$$
$$= A_2^nb_2 = A_2(A_2^{n-1}b_2)$$

Thus, $SA_1S^{-1}(A_2^kb_2) = A_2(A_2^kb_2)$ for each $0\le k\le n-1$,
and since we know that $A_2^kb_2$ form a basis, we have that 
$A_2=SA_1S^{-1}$, as desired.

Comment: @krms The first equality, $S^{-1}A_2^kb_2 = A_1^kb_1$ is the definition of $S$.

Comment: @krms $S$ is the map $A_1^kb_1 \mapsto A_2^kb_2$. Thus $S^{-1}$ is the map $A_2^kb_2\mapsto A_1^kb_1$.

Comment: @krms No. That's the definition of $S$. $S$ is the composition of the map that sends $A_1^kb_1$ to $e_1$ and then the map that sends $e_1$ to $A_2^kb_2$.

Comment: Sorry the $e_1$ was careless. That should have been $e_{k+1}$.